# Webmethod not getting hit in ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax, webmethod

I have angular js directive from where i am calling one function which has ajax post call to c# webmethod.

```
app.directive("fileread", [function () {
return {
link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
  $elm.on('change', function (changeEvent) {
   var data = "some json data";   
        test(data);           
      });
    };
  };
}]);
```

The functions which get called from directive

```
function test(json_object){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/sites/Demo/_layouts/15/demo/demowebmethod.aspx/mywebmethod",
        data: json_object,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
           alert(response.d);
        }
     });    
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
```

It is not hitting the web method neither the success or failure getting called but control goes inside `test` function. Any clues where i am going wrong.

Comment: what is the error code in your browser console??

Comment: the function is called `test1`, but you're calling `test`. couldn't be it, could it?

Comment: @Hazonko where do you see test1?

Comment: try changing `data: json_object,` to `data: JSON.stringify(json_object)` -

Comment: @VenkataKrishnaReddy i am not getting any error in console that is the issue

Comment: Are you sure you're actually calling your function test()? and that your `$elem.on('change..` is actually firing?

Comment: @Darren as per question: *"but control goes inside test function"*

Comment: @freedomn-m - how can he know. its not hitting the web api and he has no errors. hence why i think it isn't hitting his test method. would need clarifying with a console.log or something similar.

Comment: @Darren he's not "getting" errors because he's not asking for errors :)  (see 2x answers)

Comment: @KSib it was edited out since my initial comment.

Comment: What does the web method method look like in the behind file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your ajax call.  It should give you a better message to act on.

```
 error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert('Error: ' + error);
            }
```

Comment: are you certain that the path in the ajax call is correct?  Either the path is wrong, or you need to pass in more parameters, or the return type is different than you expect.

Comment: Right, so now you know your JS is calling the webmethod and the *webmethod* (C# code) is giving an error.  Debug the webmethod.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `failure` callback in $.ajax:

```
failure: function(response) {
     alert(response.d);
}
```

change this to `error:` or use the promise

```
error: function(response) {
     alert(response.d);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

It's possible that it's error-ing due to the webmethod, but you're not seeing it.  Confirm by changing the url to something that clearly doesn't exist, eg ".../mywebmethodxxxxxxx"